# assert vs null en Java

Tags: java, android

A menudo cuando estoy picando código el Android Studio me advierte que tal función puede devolver @nullable, sus recomendaciones son dos:
Englobarlo todo en un if que compruebe si el objeto, variable, función es `null` o bien usar la sentencia `assert` (que no ser para que sirve)

Ejemplo

```
final LinearLayout img = (LinearLayout) SplashActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.splashscreen);

//con checkeo si es nulo
if (img != null )
    img.setVisibility(View.GONE);

//con assert
assert img != null;
img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Que es mejor práctica y si influye en rendimiento usar una o la otra.

Comment: Espero respuesta yo también, tengo la misma duda, hasta donde tengo entendido, es para detectar fallos en tiempo de ejecución lo antes posible siempre que esté configurado el IDE con la opción -ea (enable asserts ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La palabra reservada [`assert`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.10) se utiliza en Java para realizar validaciones del código en tiempo de ejecución. Debes tener cuidado al utilizar `assert` puesto que si una evaluación falla se lanzará un `Error` (más grave que una `Exception`), específicamente un `AssertionError` y al suceder esto el programa, si el error no es controlado la aplicación (o hilo) será detenida. Por defecto, los `asserts` son ignorados por la JVM, puedes activarlos al agregar el parámetro `-enableassertions` o `-ea`. Como recomendación personal, sólo utiliza `assert` durante tiempo de debug o ejecución en entornos de desarrollo, no habilites la evaluación de `assert`s en producción. Importante: no confundir la palabra reservada `assert` con los métodos `assertXyz` de frameworks de pruebas como JUnit o TestNG, este último grupo cumplen una funcionalidad distinta.

Ahora, sobre si deberías siempre validar si la variable es `null` o no, es una cuestión de diseño. Puedes realizar lo que se llama programación defensiva, que es defender tu código de cualquier cosa que pueda afectarlo como validar si hay variables `null` y reemplazarlas con valores por defecto que no harán nada, o diseñar tu aplicación para que maneje los `NullPointerException` a un nivel superior al de tu método. Dependiendo de lo que realices, deberás elegir entre una u otra.

Sobre el código de ejemplo que colocas en la pregunta y basado en las explicaciones previas, yo recomendaría que utilices la primera forma, la de verificación de `null` puesto que tu código estará protegido ante cualquier error:

```
if (img != null )
    img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Gracias, por la explicación muy detallada

Answer (score 2):

#### Si la variable puede ser nula en tiempo de ejecución:

Debes validar que no sea nula antes de intentar acceder a un miembro de esta o de lo contrario lanzará una excepción.

Pero no solo basta con envolver el código en un `if`, debes razonar que hacer en caso que la variable si pueda venir en null y hacer otra cosa o tu mismo lanzar tu propia excepción con un mensaje de error personalizado.

#### Si se supone que la variable no pueda ser nula.

Entonces el hecho que se haya colado un valor null representa un bug. El `assert`, lo que hace es verificar esto y lanzar un `AssertionError` en caso no se cumpla. Al encontrarse con este error inmediatamente debes asumir que se trata de un error de programación y tratar de arreglar el código para que esto no vuelva a suceder.

Answer (score 2):

Un [assert](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/junit/framework/Assert.html) es un palabra reservada cuya instrucción sirve para validar en nuestro código que cuando ocurre la ejecución de la aplicación, determinada condición se debe evaluar a verdadero.

En el caso de Android no es muy usado el assert, de hecho lo puedes ver en las clases del SDK, la razón es sencilla en el caso de la maquina virtual Dalvik (Que aún es muy usada) esta configurada para ignorar por default los assert.
Además recuerda que en los emuladores los Assets estan deshabilitados por default.

En base a tu pregunta:

> Englobarlo todo en un if que compruebe si el objeto, variable, función
>   es null o bien usar la sentencia assert.

Te sugiero en el caso especifico de Android realizar la comprobación ¿es nulo?

```
if (obj==null) {
 throw new CustomError("Object cannot be null");
}
```

en tu ejemplo sugiero usar:

```
if (img != null )
    img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```