# Uso de la palabra reservada assert en android

Tags: java, android

Tengo una duda y es que el IDE AndroidStudio marca algunos warning cuando la linea de código puede producir un resultado null, en ese caso sugiere un `assert variable != null`
la pregunta es si tendria el mismo sentido que decir:

```
if (variable != null){

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estaba queriendo responderte pero en esta respuesta encontraras mas detalles sobre la diferencia entre el assert que es ejecutado en tiempo de ejecucion mientra la condicional del if realiza que si no esta en ese contexto lo ignore.

[Respuesta sobre la diferencia entre assert vs null](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6170/assert-vs-null-en-java)

Comment: si vas a dar como referencia la respuesta de otro usuario de esta misma red; entonces no va en la zona de comentarios, puesto que la respuesta es del otro usuario

Comment: No tengo el poder de ponerlo como duplicado xD , haz el favor y ponlo :) saludos.

Comment: y que debo de hacer en caso que la pregunta este duplicada? eliminarla?

Comment: jeje no dejalo no mas, y marcalo como duplicada si resolvio tu problema esa respuesta :)

Comment: dale puntuación a la otra respuesta @IgmerRodriguez para calificar si es que te resuelve la duda; de todos modos si otros usuarios tienen el mismo criterio al hacer la revisión tu pregunta siemplemente será marcada como duplicada